# indexPath variable not inheriting value

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue

I'm trying to perform a segue and pass the tapped 'audioNSURL' to my next viewController.  The issue that I have is that, in my segue, 'indexPath' is null (not inheriting the tapped value from tableView).  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
// Function for when cell is tapped in tableView
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var sound = self.sounds[indexPath.row]
    var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    var pathComponents = [baseString, sound.url]
    var audioNSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)!

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("tableViewToPlayerSegway", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "tableViewToPlayerSegway" {

    var secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as PlayViewController

        if var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {

        var sound = self.sounds[indexPath.row]
        var soundName = sound.name
        var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        var pathComponents = [baseString, sound.url]
        var audioNSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)!
        secondScene.currentSound = audioNSURL
        secondScene.soundName = sound.name
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Calling deselectRowAtIndexPath before performSegueWithIdentifier probably makes indexPathForSelectedRow return nil.  If you call performSegue first it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send indexPath of your selected cell as sender object in performSegueWithIdentifier method since you are not using it at all. Then in prepareForSegue unwrap and cast sender to NSIndexPath and use it to pass data to next controller

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var sound = self.sounds[indexPath.row]
    var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    var pathComponents = [baseString, sound.url]
    var audioNSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)!

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("tableViewToPlayerSegway", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "tableViewToPlayerSegway" {

    var secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as PlayViewController

        if var indexPath = sender as? NSIndexPath {

        var sound = self.sounds[indexPath.row]
        var soundName = sound.name
        var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        var pathComponents = [baseString, sound.url]
        var audioNSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)!
        secondScene.currentSound = audioNSURL
        secondScene.soundName = sound.name
        }

    }
}
```